# How can I block people visiting my website on a VPS in PHP?

Tags: php

Some of my visitors are using VPS (Virtual Private Server)'s to access my website. How can I stop this from happening? I have tried to research how to block this but unfortunately I can't find anything that has helped me so far.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Why specifically do you not want VPSs to access your site...?!

Comment: I don't want to explain why it's a problem, It's just most of my visitors from servers are competitors and trying to steal my website and send abuse to my website.

Comment: There is no general definition of what a "VPS" is. Blacklist them as you discover them. That's about the best you can do.

Comment: Would checking if the IP visitor has a specific port open do the job?

Comment: No. A "VPS" is just like any other computer out there on the internet. In fact, it *is* just another computer on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best you can do is block a range of IP's, for instance block all the IP's allocated to large hosting companies.  However if you have legitimate server to server communication (API's, etc) you could potentially be restricting access for them.

The problem is, if you have someone who is really set on stealing your public content, it's a battle you will lose.  Every time you block their ip they can easily switch it to a different server, use a vpn or tor.

If you have traffic coming from a server owned by a hosting company that is you believe is attacking your server (making large amount of requests, causing your service to go down) you can approach that hosting company and see if they will do anything about it.

At any rate, my advice would be, instead of focusing on how to prevent people from stealing content... Work on features that keep your users coming to you.  Find a competitive advantage you can exploit to make your site more appealing than that of one with the exact same content, and don't let people stealing content keep you up at night.